# How to make video using matplotlib with a contour filed, a vector field, and a moving box?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I tried using `plt.fill` and patches to make the rectangle, but the result is that in the video, boxes of any previous time step are presenting in the field rather than the box moving as I want it to be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I similarly make videos with `matplotlib` for my [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCh3Lf3PUvWCIge5WT7IJrhg).

Save the frames separately as `png` files using `zfill` to pad the zeroes of the id numbers that distinguish the frames. Within your Python code, you can use a counter variable or a `for` loop dummy variable to create the frame ids.

As you make each frame, be sure to make use of `plt.close()` to prevent things plotted on previous canvases from also being on the current canvas that you're plotting.

Then use `ffmpeg` to stitch the frames together at a desired frame rate. An example taken from `hamelot.io` is the following:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i pic%04d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

Some of the parameters that you might want to tweak in the above example are `-r` which is the frame rate (60 fps in the above example), `-s` the size resolution of the final video, `-i` the string pattern for your frames in `png` format (you could change this to other formats including `jpeg`), and the final argument at the end which is not flagged but it simply the name of the final video you're creating.